# Let $p$ be an odd prime and $P(x)$ a polynomial of degree $p-2$. If $p\mid P(n)+P(n+1)+...+P(n+p-1) \forall n$, must $P$ have integer coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I am stuck on this question from Zeit's book The Art and Craft of Problem Solving.

**Question**

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $P(x)$ a polynomial of degree at most $p-2$.

If $P(n)+P(n+1)+...+P(n+p-1)$ is an integer divisible by $p$ for every integer $n$, must $P$ have integer coefficients?

**Attempt**

I think $P$ must have integer coefficients. Suppose $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-2} a_k \cdot x^k$. Define $H(n)=P(n)+P(n+1)+...+P(n+p-1)$. Then we can expand $H(n)$ into a polynomial $H(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-2} c_k \cdot n^k$, where each of the coefficients $c_k$ are some linear combination of $a_k$.

If $c_i$ is not an integer for some $i$, then I think by choosing some suitable $n_i$, we can cancel all denominators of $c_j$ where $j \neq i$, while leaving $c_i$ still a fraction. Then $H(n_i)$ will be non-integer. But I don't know how to prove this properly. The $c_i$ are already very complicated to express.

However, if $c_i$ is integer for all $i$, then I am stuck.

I also don't know where to use the fact that $p\mid H(n)$ for all $n$.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is ***no***.  For example, $$P(x):=\frac{x\,(x+1)\,(x+5)}{6}$$
is not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  However, for $p=5$, we see that $P(x)$ satisfies the required conditions.  To see this, we observe that
$$\sum_{r=0}^4\,P(n+r)=5\,\left(\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{6}+2n^2+8n+11\right)$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But if we let $n=0$, then $\sum_{r=0}^4 P(n+r) = 5(-\frac{1}{6}+11)$ which is not an integer

Comment: @eatfood  Read the formula for the sum more carefully.

Comment: oops I see my mistake now. Can I ask how you came up with this counter example?

Comment: @eatfood  I set $Q(x):=\dfrac{P(x+p)-P(x)}{p}$.  Then, I know that $Q(x)$ takes integer values for integral inputs.  Thus, $Q(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^d\,q_r\,\binom{x}{r}$ for some $q_0,q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_d\in\mathbb{Z}$.  This example arises from taking $Q(x)$ to be $\displaystyle\binom{x}{2}$.

Comment: How did you know $Q(x)=\sum_{r=0}^d q_r {x\choose r}$? Is it a theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial

Comment: Alright, i understand now. Thank you for your help!